# Circumvent container in Roots Wordpress

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Wordpress page that uses roots startertheme that is based on Twitter Bootstrap. Everything in this theme is placed under a container for good looks but I have a div that I want to stretch 100% in width. I tried to add a class in which I specify width: 100% to circumvent the container but this did not work.

The container uses padding to center divs so I tried to add padding to 0px in this div but this also did not work.

Is there any way to circumvent the container for this div?

Thanks.

```
.div1{
position: relative;
top: -20px;
width: 100%;
background-color: @redColor;
padding-top: 40px;
padding-bottom: 40px;
text-align: center;
}

.container{
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: could you please post your code instead of describing it?

Comment: The only way to position an element in respect to something other than is parent is to not position it in reference to the parent - namely by positioning it absolutely with the parent *not* being positioned. The only other alternative is to use javascript to move the node outside of the container.

Comment: Basically I want to circumvent the container only with div1 so that it stretches out 100% in width. But the rest of the page should follow the rules of the container.

Comment: Ok then I will have to figur something else out. Thanks

Comment: @S4M1R If you're talking in terms of fixing it, there simply is no other way. Either you do as I mentioned or you go with a different design

Comment: I have redesigned my page so that only the posts page is dependent on the container class. And fixed the issue with php with an if statement. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do it would be to add the official Bootstrap [no-gutters](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#no-gutters) class.

If, for some reason, you cannot do then then, if you have control over the parent container styles you can remove the padding by literally deleting the line.

However, Bootstrap, by default, applies left and right padding to the `container` class. So if you're trying to override that, then you would create:

```
.container {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

You may also have to add the `!important` tag.

If you cannot modify the HTML or the parent class, you could also set your child div to a fixed width that is the container width + the padding. So if the parent container is 980 pixels wide on desktop, and it has 15 pixels of left and right padding you would make the child container 1010 pixels width, left margin of negative 15. Then, to keep it responsive, add [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) for each size and change it accordingly.

Let me know if you need further clarification.